# What's the easiest way to replace all top level heading tags with h3, second level with h4 etc. in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

If I have a string containing:-

```html
<h2>First level heading</h2>
    <p>Some text.</p>
    <h3>Next level heading</h3>
    <p>More text.</p>
```

Or a string like this:-

```html
<h4>First level heading</h4>
    <p>Some text.</p>
    <h5>Next level heading</h5>
    <p>More text.</p>
```

It should look *always* look like this:-

```html
 <h3>First level heading</h3>
    <p>Some text.</p>
    <h4>Next level heading</h4>
    <p>More text.</p>
```

Note: Whatever the first, second etc. level is, the replaced text must have this hierarchical structure: h3 > h4 > h5 > h6.

I.e. hx > hy > hz should always be h3 > h4 > h5.

More detail: I will be using this for modifying text pasted into WordPress’ TinyMCE visual editor.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery should do the trick:

```
$(function(){
   $('h1').each(function(){
       $(this).replaceWith('<h2>' + $(this).html() + '</h2>');
   });//And so on for the others
});
```

Obviously you have to include the jquery script inside of your project

Comment: But this will also replace a structure like this h3 > h4 > h5 with h4 > h5 > h6. I want hx > hy > hz to always be replaced with h3 > h4 > h5.